# If in a cyclic quadrilateral ABCD, diagonals intersect at M, prove that $\frac{BM}{MD} = \frac{AB\times BC}{DC\times AD}$

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral whose diagonals intersect at $M$. Prove that $\frac{BM}{MD} = \frac{AB\times BC}{DC\times AD}$.

Please help me with this question as I am stuck with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triangle $AMD$ is similar to triangle $BMC$ $\Rightarrow \frac{BM}{AM}=\frac{MC}{MD}\Rightarrow \frac{BM}{MD} = \frac{AM \times MC}{MD^2}$

- Triangle $ABM$ is similar to triangle $DCM$ $\Rightarrow \frac{AM}{MD} = \frac{AB}{DC}$
- Triangle $AMD$ is similar to triangle $BMC$ $\Rightarrow \frac{MC}{MD}=\frac{BC}{AD}$

Multiplying these two together gives us $\frac{AM \times MC}{MD^2} = \frac{AB\times BC}{DC\times AD}$. Hence $\frac{BM}{MD} = \frac{AB\times BC}{DC\times AD}$, as required.

(Note that the similarities are derived from angles being in the same segment)